# Python Lambda function to read CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3_obj.Bucket(BucketName)
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        reader = csv.reader(open(key,'w'),delimiter=',')
```

I'm trying to use CSV reader to open the file in S3 bucket but when I execute this it throws back an error saying:

> "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'ABC.csv'"

But the file actually exists in the bucket.

Could some one please let me know where I went wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Notwithstanding the reader/write permission issue, why are you passing the S3 object's key to a local file open? You can't read objects in S3 like that. You need to download the object from S3 to /tmp and then open it for CSV reading, or stream it from S3,

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for writing without having permission. Moreover you are trying to open an object from s3 and it is not possible. The file is not on the local file system. You should read it using:

`body = obj.get()['Body'].read()`

and then split the file into lines and pass them to csv reader:

`csv.reader(body.split('\n'),...)`

Note that if eg your file is in Windows format you might need some more processing before passing it to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.I tried 'open(key,r)' but it still throws back same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah yes sorry you are trying to read an s3 object. You can't use open. I've updated my answer.